# How to install Android SDK only?

Tags: android, sdk

I have been installing android SDK in the last couple of years without an android studio, now I need to do the same on my new PC and there's no more .exe file but just a zip file which makes things complicated. Before I was able to access the SDK manager immediately after installing the exe file, now how can I install that zip file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: open command prompt, goto sdk tools directory and execute this command=>tools/android.bat

Comment: Then how do I open sdk manager now? and the command is "tools/android.bat" or "android.bat"?

Comment: if you execute from tools directory then command is just android.bat. from sdk tools directory its tools/android.bat

Comment: @Dhaval Patel It says "android command is deprecated". This is really frustrating, I'm just going to install android studio to get the sdk manager with the interface, I don't understand why google have to remove the installer.

Answer (score 1):

As written in documentation. 
"If you do not need Android Studio, you can download the basic Android command line tools below. ***You can use the included sdkmanager to download other SDK packages***."

When you download and extract zip file, inside bin folder you will find  **sdkmanager** run it to download different versions of sdk and other tools.

Comment: When I run the bat file nothing happens except a blank terminal. I the latest version of java installed.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

Get your path variable setting right
ADD sdk route path to user variable and javahome and androidhome path to system variable.